# Good way to handle host key checking on multiple networks?

Tags: ssh

I have a laptop and multiple networks that I visit. When I'm on network Alpha, I want to `ssh 192.168.1.10`, which is a webserver. When I'm on network Beta, I want to `ssh 192.168.1.10`, which is a file-server.

Because I'm visiting two *different* machines with the *same* IP, I get the big banner

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @ 
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
```

But all that's really happening is that I'm on a different private network, so the context of my `ssh` command is different.

I know I can do `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` and bypass the check, but is there a way to keep checking (hey I'd like to know if one of the hosts actually changed) but make it network-aware?

Comment: Not enough detail to offer a specific solution but some systems allow scripts to be executed when connecting to a network. For your case `known_hosts` could be a symlink to a per-network `known_hosts` file and a script would change the link upon connection to a network.

Comment: IMO, your comment is sufficient as a solution. If you named one or two such systems that could help me find similar tools, but just with the suggestion to swap `known_hosts` around I can see how I might write my own script.

Comment: What detail would you need to offer a specific solution?

Comment: E.g. for netplan and networkd-dispatcher see https://gitlab.com/craftyguy/networkd-dispatcher. Since the networks aren't named you'd might need to use some trickery like keying off of the mac address of the default gateway. If it is wireless, however you can use the ESSID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement IPv6. Add globally unique addressees to hosts, and to DNS. Which network becomes obvious by `/64` subnets.

A big project just for your administrative convenience, maybe. But it may become a bigger problem if an organization ever merges or restructures or uses VPNs, introducing address conflicts.

Comment: Mark's answer of "mess around with `known_hosts` is what I was looking for, but I agree that this is really the correct solution -- the point of IPv6 is to allow every host a unique address and if I had that then ssh's host verification would work exactly as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Add something like this to /etc/hosts:

```
192.168.1.10    alpha-webserver    beta-fileserver
```

Then use `ssh user@alpha-webserver` or `ssh user@beta-fileserver`.

The ssh known hosts file uses the name you *give* as the key, so just use 2 different names instead of 1 IP.  Might be useful in other context also -- a name is always less error-prone than a number :)